# Derivation and Integration in polynomial spaces

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-spaces, interpolation, numerical-calculus

My german numerical-calculus-book gives an example of integration and derivation in polynomial-spaces. But I do not understand the approach.

### Question 14.2

We have a polynomial with degree n and monomial basis p(x) = $\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i = (1,x,x^2,\ldots)\,\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$
as well as a derivation p'(x) and an antiderivative P(x) where the constant of integration equals 0, represented by a coefficient vector for the monomial basis $\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{c'}$ and $ \mathbf{C}.$

I need to show that the coefficient vector $ \mathbf{c}'$ and $\mathbf{C}$ for $p'(x)$ and P(x) can be calculated with the coefficient vector $\mathbf{c}$ by matrix multiplication with $A_n$
and respectively $T_n$ . We get $p'(x)=(1,x,x^2,\ldots)\,\mathbf{c'} $
with $\mathbf{c'}= \mathbf{A}_n \mathbf{c}$ and respectively $P(x)=(1,x,x^2,\ldots)\,\mathbf{C}$ with $\mathbf{C}= \mathbf{T}_n \mathbf{c}$

More concrete I need help with the following  steps:

1. Find matrix $A_3 \in R^{3x4}$ for derivation and $T_2 \in R^{4x3}$ for integration.
2. Are $A_n$ and $T_{n-1}$ in some kind related?
3. Find $∫^1_0 p(x)$ as a linear vector of c. Find moreover the vector, which dot-product with c equals the integral.
   ​

How can I find the vector d so that $\mathbf{c}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{d} = \int_0^1 p(x)$?

\

Please note that my level of mathematics is still "in development": I am learning without a teacher.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To write $p^\prime(1,\,x,\,x^2,\,\cdots)A_nc$, work out which square matrix $A_n$ satisfies$$(1,\,x,\,x^2,\,\cdots)A_n=(0,\,1,\,2x,\,\cdots).$$Handle $T_n$ similarly. Then interpret $\int_0^1pdx=\sum_ic_i\int_0^1x^idx$ as a dot product.

Comment: Are you sure that $A_n$ needs to be a square matrix? The book says I should find $A_3 \in R^{3x4}$

Comment: @J.G. see my previous comment

Comment: I think your book's right, sorry.